# How to type `let rec f g = g f` in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, typing

Here’s what the interpreter gives me:

```
# let rec f g = g f ;;
Error: This expression has type ('a -> 'b) -> 'c
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside ('a -> 'b) -> 'c
```

It works if I pass `-rectypes` to the interpreter:

```
# let rec f g = g f ;;
val f : ('a -> 'b) -> 'b as 'a = <fun>
```

But is there a way to have it well-typed without giving an option to `ocaml`?

I don’t know how to annotate the code, because the type of `f` depends on the type of `g`, which itself depends on the type of `f`.

Comment: In order to turn off the "occurs" error you are seeing, use of the `rectypes` option [is required](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/215867/103181), so it does not appear you can do this under the type unification of `ocaml` without `rectypes`.

Comment: Do you want to have this function because you need it or is it a matter of curiosity ? If you need it, maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: @PatJ: I was trying to reproduce the `(loop [bindings] … recur [bindings])` Clojure syntax in OCaml, with `let rec loop bindings body = body bindings loop`, but if you know the `loop`/`recur` syntax in Clojure, it can be transposed to OCaml with recursive function and an accumulator instead of passing a callback function. TL;DR: no I don’t need it, it was just an experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you cannot have it to type check, the reason having been explained by other answers.

You may however get an approximation by wrapping the function parameter with a polymorphic variant:

```
# let rec f (`F g) = g (`F f);;
val f: [< `F of [> `F of 'a ] -> 'b ] -> 'b = <fun>
```

The result of applying this function depends on the behaviour of its parameter:

```
# f (`F (fun _ -> 13));
-: int = 13
# f (`F f);; (* infinite recursion *)
^CInterrupted
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to circumvent this without using `-rectypes`.